# How can I save the 'creating of a new instance of a fragment' in a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, instantiation

I have a method, which iterates over an array. Based on the contents of that array, it should create new instances of (different) fragments, and set some textviews on them. I am however having some issues with making sure the fragment I'm adding is a new instance of that fragment. I tried storing the "creation of new fragment" like this: `Fragment myFragment = new myFragment();`.

This works when the array only contains one entry, but when there's more fragments to be added, it throws an error:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment myFragment`, basically telling me I'm not creating a new instance, but using the same instance.

I also tried using `Fragment myFragment = myFragment.newInstance();`, with the basic `newInstance()` method, which gave me the exact same error.

```
public static myFragment newInstance() {
    return new myFragment();
}
```

So, how can I store the creation of a new instance of a fragment in a variable (`fragmentVariable` in the example below), which will be used like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentVariable, "tag").
}
```

*PS. I suspect I'm doing this in a bad and dumb way, but I'm just having some fun, creating an app purely for myself.*

**DrawVariableFragments method**

```
public void DrawVariableFragments(String base,String token){

    ArrayList<String> Data;
    dbHandler = DBHandler.getInstance(this);

    int AmountOfEntries;
    int SettingsContainer;
    String SettingsTag;
    Fragment SettingsVariableFragment;
    Fragment SettingsEmptyFragment;

    if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
        Log.d(tag, "StuffManager");
        Data = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("StuffManager"); add("name"); add("tag"); }};
        SettingsContainer = R.id.FragmentContainer2;
        SettingsTag = getString(R.string.navdrawer_stuffmanager);
        SettingsVariableFragment = new StuffManagerVariableFragment();
        SettingsEmptyFragment = new StuffManagerEmptyFragment();
    } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
        Log.d(tag, "GeneralSettings");
        Data = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("GeneralSettings"); add("name"); add("ip"); add("port"); add("username"); add("pass"); }};
        SettingsContainer = R.id.FragmentContainerGeneralSettings;
        SettingsTag = getString(R.string.navdrawer_generalsettings);
        SettingsVariableFragment = new GeneralSettingsVariableFragment();
        SettingsEmptyFragment = new GeneralSettingsEmptyFragment();
    } else {
        Log.e(tag, "String Base not recognised");
        return;
    }
    AmountOfEntries = dbHandler.returnArray(base, Data.get(1)).size();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SettingsTag).getChildFragmentManager();

    // ****
    // If no devices/links are set up=
    // ****

    if (AmountOfEntries == 0 ) {
        Log.d(tag, "AmountOfEntries == 0");
        fm.beginTransaction().add(SettingsContainer, SettingsEmptyFragment, (base + "EmptyFragment")).commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        return;
    }

    // ****
    // If more then 0 devices/links are set up
    // ****

    if (AmountOfEntries > 0) {
        Log.d(tag, "AmountOfEntries > 0");

        // ****
        // Remove 'no devices created' fragment if available
        // ****
        String EmptyFragName = (base + "EmptyFragment");
        if ((fm.findFragmentByTag(EmptyFragName)) != null) {
            Log.d(tag, "EmptyFragment removed");
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentByTag(EmptyFragName)).commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }

        // ****
        //
        // ****

        for (int iEntry = 0; iEntry < AmountOfEntries; iEntry++) {     // For each entry
            ArrayList<String> fragmentData = new ArrayList<>();         // Create new Array for every entry

            // ****
            // Create and fill FragmentData array
            // ****

            Log.d(tag, "Data array size = " + Data.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.size(); i++) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    fragmentData.add((dbHandler.returnArray(base, Data.get(i))).get(iEntry));
                }
            }

//            for (String s : fragmentData) {
//                Log.d(" FD " + tag, "fragmentData " + s);
//            }

            // ****
            // Do based on token
            // ****

            if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
                ((LinearLayout) findViewById(SettingsContainer)).removeAllViews();
                DrawVariableFragments(base ,"draw");
            } else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                if (fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(0)) == null) {
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(SettingsContainer, SettingsVariableFragment, fragmentData.get(0)).commit();
                    fm.executePendingTransactions();
                    if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
                        ((StuffManagerVariableFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(0)))
                                .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1));
                    } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
                        ((GeneralSettingsVariableFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(0)))
                                .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1), fragmentData.get(2), fragmentData.get(3));
                    }
                }
            } else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("draw")) {
                fm.beginTransaction().add(SettingsContainer, SettingsVariableFragment, fragmentData.get(0)).commit();
                fm.executePendingTransactions();
                if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("StuffManager")) {
                    ((StuffManagerVariableFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(0)))
                            .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1));
                } else if (base.equalsIgnoreCase("GeneralSettings")) {
                    ((GeneralSettingsVariableFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(fragmentData.get(0)))
                            .setText(fragmentData.get(0), fragmentData.get(1), fragmentData.get(2), fragmentData.get(3));
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TEST", "WTF, nameArray.size != 0 && !> 0");
    }
}
```

`dbHandler.returnArray(arg1, arg2)` returns an ArrayList, which contains all entries for column `arg2` from the SQLite table by the name `arg1`.

Comment: Can you show the complete code where you are creating new instances of fragments based on the contents of the array?

Comment: You can, but it's a clusterF at the moment. Give me a minute to clear it up and add it.

Comment: I see what you mean by clusterF :P The issue is you only create one new instance of `SettingsVariableFragment` outside the for loop but you might add it multiple times inside the for loop. It isn't clear to me what the purpose of this method is so it is hard to suggest how to fix it. You could at least move the creation of the `SettingsVariableFragment` inside the for loop to see what happens but this method looks like it has more problems than that. I'm not sure why you want to add the same fragment type multiple times to the same container.

Comment: Imagine what you see in the link below, but with multiple sections like that. What you see (name --> passwrd) is one fragment, added to the container (entire empty screen). If I had another device set up (can't right now, will crash if I try), it would show a second version of this fragment below it, just with different values. 
http://imgur.com/QYf3PPp

Comment: Also, your suggestion about moving the creation of the fragment inside the loop worked just fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see. If that is the case I would suggest not use fragments for that. It would be better to use something like a `RecyclerView` where each item in the `RecyclerView` produces the view in your image.

Comment: I'm not aware about the workings of a RecyclerView. I will look in to that, thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with a `ListView`? They are similar except `RecyclerView` is now typically the preferred method of showing a collection of items.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm familiar with LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and GridLayout and ScrollView, and that's basically it. All my knowledge about developing comes from looking up info about what I currently need / am running in to, so I only know about a random collection of things I've used sometime.

Answer (score 1):

All credits go to [George Mulligan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435985/george-mulligan).

His suggestion was to move the creation of the new fragment inside the loop that iterates over the array, which worked like a charm.

Also, as an addition, he suggested to look into a `RecyclerView` for what I was trying to do (which is adding multiple instances of the same thing in a list shape).